# How to automate burpsuite with C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, security-testing

I have been trying to automate burpsuite using selenium with C# , I couldn't find any elements in the burpsuite.

I couldnt find the elements of the "Next" button in the burpsuite community version.

Comment: You need to share the relevant code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium WebDriver is used to control the Burp Suite.
You may need to use "BurpExtender", a separate library for controlling Burp Suite with WebDriver.

```
using burp;

public class BurpExtender : IBurpExtender, ITab
{
    private IExtensionHelpers helpers;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public void registerExtenderCallbacks(IBurpExtenderCallbacks callbacks)
    {
        // obtain an extension helpers object
        helpers = callbacks.getHelpers();

        // set up UI components
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        // customize UI components as needed
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        // add the custom tab to Burp Suite UI
        callbacks.customizeUiComponent(scrollPane);
        callbacks.addSuiteTab(this);
    }

    public String getTabCaption()
    {
        return "My Custom Tab";
    }

    public Component getUiComponent()
    {
        return scrollPane;
    }
}
```

Comment: why "using burp;" is showing error?